# echo -ne "${none}" every other line when using editor for commands

Tags: bash, shell, editor

I've been having an issue with `echo -ne "${none}"` displaying every other line when issuing commands from the shell editor `ctrl-x e`

For example entering `for i in what is going on ? ; do echo "$i"; done`  will print out

```
echo -ne "${none}"
echo -ne "${none}"
what
echo -ne "${none}"
echo -ne "${none}"
is
echo -ne "${none}"
echo -ne "${none}"
going
echo -ne "${none}"
echo -ne "${none}"
on
echo -ne "${none}"
echo -ne "${none}"
R
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. It doesn't seem to have an effect on things, but makes reading the output kind of a pain.

---

So I think I've worked out why I am getting the 'echo -ne "${none}"' only from editor.

I have edited my .bashrc do include the **fancy bash prompt** from https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell . do colourise my bash prompt.

```
        ############################################################################
        ## BASH PROMT                                                             ##
        ## Generate promt and remove format from the rest                         ##
        ############################################################################
        PS1="$TITLEBAR\n${PROMT_USER}${SEPARATOR_1}${PROMT_HOST}${SEPARATOR_2}${PROMT_PWD}${SEPARATOR_3}${PROMT_INPUT}"



        ## For terminal line coloring, leaving the rest standard
        none="$(tput sgr0)"
        trap 'echo -ne "${none}"' DEBUG
```

I assume that entering commands from the editor doesn't set the none variable

Comment: What does `type echo` say? I suspect it's an alias that does this.

Comment: I get `echo is a shell builtin` . Looking typing in `alias` at command prompt gives me a few alias for `ls` and `grep` nothing for echo.

Comment: What do you mean by shell editor? The default binding of `C-x e` is `call-last-kbd-macro`

Comment: Does this happen **only** when you do a ctrl-x e, or also when you edit a previous command in the normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to inspect your `bash` non-interactive shell initiation/termination process.

It seems each time a non-interactive shell command is called and terminated you receive  `echo -ne "${none}"`

#### Suggestion 1

One trick to identify the current bash functions that includes `echo -ne` :

```
set |grep -B 20 "echo -ne"
```

This command will print the 20 lines above each `echo -ne`  command.

#### Suggestion 2

Inspect bash initiation/termination scripts:

```
sudo grep "echo -ne " ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile /etc/profile /etc/bashrc /etc/profile.d/*
```

#### Suggestion 3

Check configuration of your shell prompt `PS1`, it might be unsupported by your terminal (colors, bolds, fonts,...)

```
sudo grep PS1 ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile /etc/profile /etc/bashrc /etc/profile.d/*
```

#### Suggestion 4

Test if this behavior is consistent when you are using text only session (TUI) without GUI.

If this problem appears only in GUI environment you have configuration problem with your terminal `TTY` configuration and/or prompt `PS1` .